# Query using two tables with DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - clients and - group

I need to get county and zip from clients and group-assigned from group

When I search, I cannot get distinct results, that is, instead of the output showing 100 clients with zipcode 12345 in jones county in main st group.

I need to have each zip and county listed once by group.  I have googled and attempted many ways but it is just beyond me.

Can anyone assist in steering me to the correct way

Comment: can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Can you show us your actual query (and possibly tables)?

Comment: Can you show some specific examples of the data in the tables and what you would like the result set to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `GROUP BY group, city, zip` to the end of your query should get you what you need.  It will only return unique combinations of the three.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have something like:

```
select g.*, c.county, c.zip
from clients c join groups g on <some join condition>
```

You want one result per group.  So, add a `group by` clause such as:

```
group by g.id  -- assuming id uniquely identifies each group
```

This will give an *arbitrary* value for the other fields, which may be sufficient for what you are doing.  (This uses a MySQL features called Hidden Columns.)